# Batch file needed to delete a subset of folders based on folder name

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of folder names dirprint.txt, which came from a SQL query, that I need to delete those subfolders from a temp folder.  They're all in a format similar to this: 1.3242.42353.23.12345.22345.0.2

I'm looking to create a batch file that goes through the list and deletes the corresponding folders (and contents) from C:\temp.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have a tmp folder with in other folders and you wanna delete the folders which the name match with the names in dirprint.txt ? if yes, in which environment?

Comment: There are thousands of examples using a [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to parse/iterate file content here on [SO]. What about using the search box above?

Comment: Frank...correct in Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

In windows :

```
FOR /F %i IN (pathto\dirprint.txt) DO rmdir C:\temp\%i
```